# How to insert Padding on an image drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-drawable

I am combining two images using `LayerDrawable`.

```
            Resources r = getResources();
            Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2]; 
            layers[0] = bitMapDrawable_1;
            layers[1] = bitMapDrawable_2;
            LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);

            picView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

Everything is working fine, but the problem is **Padding**.  I want to set padding on only one of the drawables, either bitMapDrawable_1 or bitMapDrawable_2.

The Two image files are :

[image: 1st Layer]
[image: 2nd Layer]

Now , i want this :

[image]

But , i m having this one :

[image]

Comment: Thnx for response,but its not working for me.

Comment: Because, probably, your images don't share the same SIZE in px. If one is 512*512 px, the other one also must be 512*512 px. Both must ne centered on a transparent background. When you'll overlay them, they'll mix well. The inner image "fill" must be smaller than 512px and leave a "padding" which is equal to the other image stroke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<LayerList>
<item paddingTop = 4dp drawable: "@drawable/bitmapDrawable_2" />
<LayerList>
```

In here, basicly, we are wrapping your bitmapDrawable with layerlist and using its padding attribute. Next, we are going to use this wrapper drawable.

Good luck.